# Show/Hide the Custom ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

Can anybody guide me how can i Show/Hide the Custom ListView (BaseAdapter based) from my Activity.

For some more elaboration I have an activty which has a BUTTON and a LISTVIEW, I have an Inner Class MyAdapter extends with Base Adapter.

Now pressing a BUTTON on my ACTIVITY SHOW/HIDE the ListView.

CAn anybody guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `visibility` of your `ListView` on the press of the button. using this line:

```
listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

To show.
and:

```
listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to hide.

you can also use: `listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` to hide the listView but still take it's screen place.

Comment: I exactly Did that, BUT my complete View GONE BLACK :(

Comment: you can try then to use:

listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); to hide it.

Comment: I used that, MY COMPLETE VIEW has gone BLACK

Comment: SOLVED. :) WORKED PERFECTLY FINE VIEW.INVISIBLE TRICK :P

Comment: well you can try to remove all the items in your data set tat is connected to the adapter to leave the listview empty.

Comment: @sHaH, Great, have a nice coding : )

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Using a toggle button:

```
public class ShowHideListViewActivity extends Activity {

ToggleButton tb;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylistviewlayout);

    tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    //You could set ListView Adapter here.

    tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked)
            {
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                //lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
 }
}
```

> XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ToggleButton" 
    android:textOn="Show"
    android:textOff="Hide"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="406dp" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```